# How can I keep a number in specific range?

Tags: php, function

I have a function like this:

```
<?php

function keepInRange($n){

    $min = 5;
    $max = 15;

    if ( $n < $min ) {
        $res = $min;
    } elseif ( $n > $max ) {
        $res = $max;
    } else {
        $res = $n;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

It always returns a number between `$min` and `$max`. It works as well, but doesn't seem clean an professional to me. I think it can be better *(without those conditions)*. Any idea how can I make it shorter and cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to make it shorter *(and probably cleaner)* and also removing those `if` statements, you can use `max()` and `min()` functions:

```
function keepInRange($n){
    $min = 5;
    $max = 15;
    return max(min($max, $n), $min);
}
```

---

Also as @admcfajn mentioned, you can pass `$min` and `$max` as arguments to make the function more flexible:

```
function keepInRange($n, $min = 5, $max = 15){
    return max(min($max, $n), $min);
}
```

Comment: I'd also suggest passing min & max as arguments `keepInRange($n, $min = 5, $max = 15)`

Comment: @admcfajn Good idea .. I just was following what the OP has written.

Comment: Thanks @shafizadeh, nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely its not the best way, You can use Rand() to generate numbers between a particular range.

Try this

```
print rand(10, 30) . "";​
```

It'll generate and print a random number between 10 and 30 (10 and 30 are included).

Answer (score 0):

> I think it can be better (without those conditions). Any idea how can I make it shorter and cleaner?

Well if you want it without explicit conditions, then you could simply use min() and max():

```
function keepInRange2($n) {
  $min = 5;
  $max = 15;
  return max($min, min($max, $n));
}
```

The order of the functions and parameters might seem odd at first glance - but since you want 15 to be the *maximum* value, we need to get the *minimum* of 15 and whatever the value is first - and then vice versa for the minimum 5.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved cleaner using ternary operator.

```
function keepInRange($n){

    $min = 5;
    $max = 15;

    return ( $n < $min ) ? $min : (( $n > $max ) ? $max : $n);
}
```